# Online resources for KFP products

Tags: kashrut-kosher, passover, product-recommendation, internet

Does anyone have a reliable list (or lists) of Kosher for Passover products that is (or are) available online?

{There are several that I've used in the past, but they seem to be cut off in their online versions this year. I'm specifically looking for what toothpastes are good for this year, but I assumed that would be too localized.}

Comment: Your dog eats toothpaste??!

Comment: @l' See Page 60 of the [Star-K Passover Guide for 2012](http://star-k.org/kashrus/star-k12_pesach_directory.pdf), note 5. "Mouthwash and Toothpaste contain sorbitol and other ingredients which may be derived from chometz. Although, l’halacha these items are permissible to use since they are nifsal mayachilas kelev, many prefer not to use them as they are taken orally. The list provides information regarding such products." Unfortunately the Guide ends at about page 100 and the list begins around page 150. Hence my frustration!

Comment: Does it cite a halachic reason for it to be asur because it's taken orally? Cuz if not, it sounds like your classic מנהג שטות to me.

Comment: It doesn't say it's Asur at all. It just says that people are strict because it's taken orally. I think the basis is that if you'll eat it, your typical "out" of it being unpalatable _even_ to a dog (not specifically to a dog) is out the window - at least by all semblance of logic.

Comment: @l' I forgot to tag you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kosherquest](http://www.kosherquest.org/Passover-2012.pdf) is run by a known Rav dealing in Kashrus (both throughout the year and on Pesach). He wrote "[Is It Kosher?](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1583306161)"

Answer (score 0):

You can get much information from the [crc chicago](http://www.crcweb.org/passover2012.php) website.